# Adding single quotes to a string returned from UI in SQL Server

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string passed from the UI to SQL Serever stored procedure as

```
Customer_name = xyz and loc = dfg and area= kmn
```

I need to code it in such a way that my final result should be

```
Customer_name = 'xyz' and loc = 'dfg' and area= 'kmn'
```

and if the input string from UI is

```
Customer_name = xyz and loc = dfg
```

then

```
Customer_name = 'xyz' and loc = 'dfg'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where / How / From which application are you calling this? I'm quite sure, that this approach is completely wrong! You should not bother about quotes but rather send your statements with typed parameters...

Comment: Angular JS is calling a proc present in SQL DB. and one of the input parameters are the string mentioned in the question. The single quotes are used around the values as it will be used in further queries for updation

Comment: Well, I know why you think to need quotes. But the correct way is `Customer_name = @prmName and loc = @prmLoc` where you pass the needed values as typed parameters. Use the edit option of your query, add some details, look for formatting and **set the proper tags (e.g. Angular JS)**

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)